# Nesting if else statements

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a large dataset I need to recode. Each row of the dataset is a possible detection from separate experiments (id) in chronological order (time). Each possible detection is then manually verified. When the first true detection is made it is marked (comments) 'first' when the last true detection is made it is marked 'last'. If there is no detection then 'none' is entered.

I am approaching recoding with if statements. 1) First I want to select all cases for the variable id where first and last are both present, then it needs to fill in everything between first and last with 'no_comment', then it needs to fill in everything before or after first and last with "MVND". 2) Select the id cases where only "none" is present and populate "none" in all rows of that id case.  The individual lines of code are working, but for some reason they aren't working together when I combine them in an if statement within ddply - they just return the original data.frame. I assume I have the wrong if else structure for what I want to do.

```
#approximate data structure for this case:
y <-data.frame(id=c(rep("a",10),rep("b",10),rep("c",10)),time=rep(1:10, 3), Comments=rep(NA,30))
 y$Comments[c(2,11,23)]<-"first"
 y$Comments[c(9,19,30)]<-"last"
 #x=y[y$id=="a",] #testing specific lines
 
#recursive process to step through the data
 ddply(y,.(id), .fUN=function(x){
 if(all(unique(na.omit(x$Comments))%in%c("first","last"))){
  f<-which(x$Comments == "first")
  l<-which(x$Comments == "last")  
  #Add no comment to all records between first and last
   x$Comments[(f+1):(l - 1)]<- "no_comment"
      #if 'first' isn't the first record add MVND to all things before 'first'    
       if(f>1){x$Comments[1:(f-1)]<-"MVND"} 
      #if 'last' isn't the last record add MVND to all records after 'last'.
       if(l<nrow[x]){x$Comments[(l+1):nrow(x)]<-"MVND"} 
 }else if(unique(na.omit(x$Comments))=="none"){
    x$Comments<-"none" #if the only unique comment is "none" set all comments to none
}
 }
 )
```

if data tables are a better way to do this I am game to find out how to do this in a dt.

#Edit: the above was revised to expand the two types of cases I am dealing with "first/last" and "none". Jon spring's solution worked admirably for how I had initially posted the example data with only a first/last case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task, my preferred approach is `data.table` for 2 reasons:

1. it is possible to update parts of a column in place, i.e., without copying
2. we can *update in a non-equi join* using a look-up table

To cover all use cases mentioned by the OP, we need to create an enhanced sample dataset

```
y <- data.frame(
  id = rep(letters[1:5], each = 5L),
  time = rep(1:5, 5L),
  Comments = rep(NA_character_, 25L))
y$Comments[c(2, 6, 13, 22)] <- "first"
y$Comments[c(4, 9, 15, 23)] <- "last"
y$Comments[c(18)] <- "none"

y
```

> ```
>    id time Comments
> 1   a    1     <NA>
> 2   a    2    first
> 3   a    3     <NA>
> 4   a    4     last
> 5   a    5     <NA>
> 6   b    1    first
> 7   b    2     <NA>
> 8   b    3     <NA>
> 9   b    4     last
> 10  b    5     <NA>
> 11  c    1     <NA>
> 12  c    2     <NA>
> 13  c    3    first
> 14  c    4     <NA>
> 15  c    5     last
> 16  d    1     <NA>
> 17  d    2     <NA>
> 18  d    3     none
> 19  d    4     <NA>
> 20  d    5     <NA>
> 21  e    1     <NA>
> 22  e    2    first
> 23  e    3     last
> 24  e    4     <NA>
> 25  e    5     <NA>
> ```

Now, we can insert the missing `Comments`

```
library(data.table)
y <- setDT(copy(y))
# copy "none" to all rows of the id group in case one Comment is "none" 
y[, Comments := if (isTRUE(any(Comments == "none"))) "none" , by = id][]
# create look-up table
lut <- dcast(y[which(Comments %in% c("first", "last"))], id ~ Comments, value.var = "time")
# update in non-equi joins
y[lut, on = .(id, time < first), Comments := "MVND"][]
y[lut, on = .(id, time > last), Comments := "MVND"][]
y[lut, on = .(id, time > first, time < last), Comments := "no commments"][]
```

> ```
>     id time     Comments
>  1:  a    1         MVND
>  2:  a    2        first
>  3:  a    3 no commments
>  4:  a    4         last
>  5:  a    5         MVND
>  6:  b    1        first
>  7:  b    2 no commments
>  8:  b    3 no commments
>  9:  b    4         last
> 10:  b    5         MVND
> 11:  c    1         MVND
> 12:  c    2         MVND
> 13:  c    3        first
> 14:  c    4 no commments
> 15:  c    5         last
> 16:  d    1         none
> 17:  d    2         none
> 18:  d    3         none
> 19:  d    4         none
> 20:  d    5         none
> 21:  e    1         MVND
> 22:  e    2        first
> 23:  e    3         last
> 24:  e    4         MVND
> 25:  e    5         MVND
>     id time     Comments
> ```

The look-up table  `lut` contains the times where `first` and `last` occur, resp.:

> ```
>    id first last
> 1:  a     2    4
> 2:  b     1    4
> 3:  c     3    5
> 4:  e     2    3
> ```

Note that we assume that the production data set "behaves nice", i.e,

- any `id` group contains either `"none"`
- or exactly one pair of `"first"` and `"last"` in the `Comments` column
- and `"first"` always occurs before `"last"`.

Comment: That extends nicely to the production data set - data.table never ceases to amaze me. I have not encountered "on" can you point me to the documentation on that? I don't quite understand why `y[lut, on = .(id, time > first, time < last)` works but `y[lut, on = .(id, time < first, time > last)` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

No sure if useful to you, but here's how I'd approach in `dplyr`. Since this is vectorized, I expect it would run faster than a loop-based approach.

```
library(dplyr)
y %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Comments2 = case_when(     # in case `plyr` is loaded
    cumsum(coalesce(lag(Comments == "last"), FALSE)) >= 1 ~ "MVND",
    cumsum(coalesce(Comments == "first", FALSE)) < 1 ~ "MVND",
    is.na(Comments) ~ "no_comment",
    TRUE ~ Comments)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

The tricky parts here are the MVND bookends, where I count if we have passed a `last` or haven't reached a `first`. `coalesce` converts any NA in the first term to the `FALSE` value in the 2nd term. `cumsum` here adds up the `TRUE` values.

Here's the result I get, pasted using `datapasta` as a tribble. The output looks as expected, as far as I can tell:

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~time, ~Comments,   ~Comments2,
  "a",    1L,        NA,       "MVND",
  "a",    2L,   "first",      "first",
  "a",    3L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "a",    4L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "a",    5L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "a",    6L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "a",    7L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "a",    8L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "a",    9L,    "last",       "last",
  "a",   10L,        NA,       "MVND",
  "b",    1L,   "first",      "first",
  "b",    2L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "b",    3L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "b",    4L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "b",    5L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "b",    6L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "b",    7L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "b",    8L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "b",    9L,    "last",       "last",
  "b",   10L,        NA,       "MVND",
  "c",    1L,        NA,       "MVND",
  "c",    2L,        NA,       "MVND",
  "c",    3L,   "first",      "first",
  "c",    4L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "c",    5L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "c",    6L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "c",    7L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "c",    8L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "c",    9L,        NA, "no_comment",
  "c",   10L,    "last",       "last"
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a crack at it. That answer looks like it should work, but when I run it on my computer, it is only doing it for that first case, not on the subsequent two cases. y2$Comments2... somehow group_by(id) is not doing what it should.

Comment: Do you get a different answer on your sample data than I do, or are you saying you get an unexpected result when running on separate data?

Comment: This might be a `plyr`/`dplyr` names conflict issue, since they unfortunately share a few function names.   http://krlmlr.github.io/pdlyr/vignettes/pdlyr.html    I'll edit to make those explicit in the code.

Comment: Ok, must be one of those odd conflicts I hear about but had not yet encountered.

Comment: It does answer the specific case I posted, but it does not seem to work with the full suite of cases in the data. It seems I went too minimal on the MRE and should have included several other cases. I am going to revise the original post.